# Naming and referring to a chart in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to create charts in excel using VBA . The code is as follows :

```
Sub testmacro()    
    Dim i As Integer     
    i = Sheets("Data").Range("M2").Value
  Sheets("Email ID").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    If i = 1 Then  
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Data!$E$1:$F$3")        
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
       .
       .
       .        
    End If     

    If i = 2 Then

   End if

   If i=3 Then  

    End If   

End Sub
```

Now, I want to be able to perform the actions when i=2 and i=3 on the same chart i created when i=1

However, I am not able to do so.

So can anyone help me **how to give a name for the chart i created when i=1 and be able to refer to it whie i=2 and i=3**??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to assign a name to a chart:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ch As Shape
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    Set ch = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    ch.Name = "First Chart"
End Sub
```

Comment: and could you also include in your answer, how to refer to it in future cases in the vba code? I mean how to call it?

Answer (score 6):

Kira, you can change the chart name by code using:

```
yourchart.Name = "Name"
```

Or in the worksheet you can select the chart, go to the `Layout` Tab and in the right edge there will be a text box saying `Chart Name`

then you can refer to it in your vba code using

```
Worksheets("yoursheet").ChartObjects("Name").PropertyYouWant
```